# Matching log entry with custon Fail2ban regex

Tags: linux, fail2ban

I'm running Fail2ban on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Buster.  Fail2ban version v0.10.2. One applicaton on it is running a simple python HTTP server script.

I'm trying to match this kind of record from the log file:

> Dec  4 07:50:00 Pi-New HTTP_Server[585]: 123.456.789.123 - - [04/Dec/2022 07:50:00] code 400, message Bad request version ('\xc0\x13\xc0')

I have tried numerous regex lines.  These are the latest lines, all without success

```
1. '^.*\]: <HOST> - - .* 400, $'
2. "^.*\]: <HOST> - - \[\+0000\].* 400, $"
```

The latter when I read a posting that fail2ban deletes out the date section before passing to the regex line

The output from fail2ban-regex is always like this:

> ## Running tests
>
> Use   failregex line : ^.*]:  - - [+0000].* 400, $ Use
> single line : Dec  4 07:50:00 Pi-New HTTP_Server[585]:...
>
> ## Results
>
> Failregex: 0 total
>
> Ignoreregex: 0 total
>
> Date template hits: |- [# of hits] date format |  [1] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY
> )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)? `-
>
> Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 1 missed [processed in 0.03 sec]
>
> |- Missed line(s): |  Dec  4 07:50:00 Pi-New
> HTTP_Server[585]: 123.456.789.123 - - [04/Dec/2022 07:50:00] code 400,
> message Bad request version ('\xc0\x13\xc0')

which seems to indicate that it found the date but after that did not find any matches.  What am I doing wrong?...RDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expressions, `$` asserts position at the end of a line, but the log line does not end with `400,` .

The following regular expression matches your log line if you are not interested in the more specific reason for the HTTP error `400`. You might want to make it more restrictive to avoid any false positives, but this is in a format you could play with, e.g., in https://regex101.com/.

```
^.*\[[0-9]+\]: ([0-9.]+) - - \[.+\] code 400,.*$
```

When ready,

- the matching group `([0-9.]+)` is a quick and dirty match for IP addresses: it should be replaced with the `<host>` to detect it.
- the `.*\[[0-9]+\]:` can probably be replaced with the `%(__prefix_line)s`.

The final fail2ban filter would look something like this:

```
^%(__prefix_line)s <host> - - \[.+\] code 400,.*$
```

Also take a look at the [Developing Filters](https://fail2ban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html#developing-filters) article in the Fail2Ban documentation.

Comment: Many thanks, you have pointed me along the right path.  After several Fail2ban_regex iterations I finally got to something which I wanted. This is what I will try as a filter "^.*\]: (<HOST>) - - \[.+\]( code (400|404|501|505), message).*$"

Comment: I may also refine the "message" to be "message (Fail|Bad|Unsupported|Invalid)"